# How do I make `ifup wlan0` return immediately if no dhcp lease can be obtained?

Tags: networking, wireless, dhclient

I have a small wireless embedded system based on Ubuntu 16.04. If the wireless interface is improperly configured or the access point is down, `ifup wlan0` will never finish because `dhclient` doesn't daemonize itself until after it obtains a lease. This is a problem because `ifdown wlan0` hangs due to the lock `ifup` is still holding:

```
ifdown: waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.wlan0
```

How do I solve this?

- Option 1: `pkill -f 'ifup .*wlan0'; ifdown wlan0`

This is crude, but if I have to do this, I will. I'd rather have a better solution.

- Option 2: `dhclient` supports a `-nw`, nowait, option that tells it to daemonize immediately, but `ifup` doesn't use it and it seems that the `dhclient` command is hard-coded in `ifup` via a source file named `inet.defn`:

.

```
$ apt-get source ifupdown
$ grep -n 'dhclient -1' ifupdown-*/inet.defn | head -1
97:    /sbin/dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.%iface%.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.%iface%.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.%iface%.leases %iface% \
```

- Option 3: is there a way to make the dhcp be controlled by the status from wpa_supplicant? So, dhclient wouldn't run until wpa_supplicant completes the association to the access point.

---

Extra information:

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# ifplugd configuration
mapping hotplug
script grep
map eth0
map wlan0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  wpa-driver wext
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

---

`/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
   ssid="AccessPoint"
   scan_ssid=1
   proto=WPA RSN
   key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
   pairwise=CCMP TKIP
   group=CCMP TKIP
   psk="passphrase"
   priority=10
}
network={
   key_mgmt=NONE
   priority=0
   disabled=1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a while, and doing a simple :

```
$ systemctl enable netctl.service
$ systemctl start netctl.service
```

Fixed everything on my ubuntu 17.04.

Hope it helps.